# Ubuntu 20.04 GDM3 Root Login GUI How Can I Disable Security Notification

Tags: ubuntu, root, gnome, security-policy, gdm

firstly sorry for my english because im trying to explain my question yours.

System Details;
Ubuntu 20.04
GDM3 (GUI) Installed
VNC Connection Installed
Root Login Enabled for login screen & SSH
Automatic Login Enabled login screen

everythings good working but. on internet everywhere i checked and ubuntu sources i checked no have about this information to disable when login after notification about security message

Message is ;

title   : ' Logged in as a privileged user    ',
message : ' Running a session as a privileged user should be avoided for security reasons. If possible, you should log in as a normal user. '

[image]
I Want To Disable This Notification Message. Please if you know can you help me my colleagues

Answer (score 0):

This is baked into gnome. For anyone who stumble here, this is what I did on Ubuntu 22.04:

Follow the general method described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305948/where-are-gnome-shells-ui-javascript-files-on-ubuntu-20-04) to make any change to gnome js files.

In this case, the file we need is ui/main.js. Replace this chunk

```
    let credentials = new Gio.Credentials();
    if (credentials.get_unix_user() === 0) {
        notify(_('Logged in as a privileged user'),
               _('Running a session as a privileged user should be avoided for security reasons. If possible, you should log in as a normal user.'));
    } else if (sessionMode.showWelcomeDialog) {
        _handleShowWelcomeScreen();
    }
```

with

```
if (sessionMode.showWelcomeDialog) {
    _handleShowWelcomeScreen();
}
```

Disclaimer: Running a session as a privileged user should be avoided for security reasons. If possible, you should log in as a normal user.